# Error when trying to add class to parent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have trying to add a class to parent div of my link like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".food-result").on("click", "a", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).parent().parent().addclass('active');


            return false; 
        });
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May we take a look at the relevant markup (HTML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo in `addclass` method name. Try `addClass`. [More details](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".food-result").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
        return false; // I am not sure if this is needed
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to get the parent of the parent which might not exist would this work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".food-result").on("click", "a", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');


        return false; 
    });
```

Comment: addclass should be addClass - view Max's answer